# Issues caused due to lack on unbinds on a page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, browser, client-side

I have a web application that runs on a mobile device(64 MB memory).

The application is a wizard that asks for input from a user to validate it with the data. 
At each step it validates a single piece of data.

The application does a post in each step and then renders the response returned by the server. This continues until all the steps are done and then it redirects back to the homepage.

Now I have a weird issue on the device where the device crashed after a few steps. On some slogging and deeper investigation, I found that the application does not unbind event handlers like clicks etc and unbinding the event handlers on page unload fixed this issue.

Now in a case of post and render response, I assumed that the browser would automatically unbind all the events. Does it not do so? Are multiple event bindings a big load on the device memory? What is happening at the browser level?

Comment: Which browser?  They each (sadly) behave differently.  It's probably an issue with how often it is deciding to do it's own garbage collection.

Comment: It's a mobile browser called wavelink industrial browser. I used it on a motorola device mc9090.